# I need to save a copy of a google spreadsheet to a specific directory using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-docs

We currently have a nightly balancing process wherein we open an Excel template spreadsheet, enter the correct processing date, and then click a button, causing a VB script to fire off and create a new copy of the spreadsheet with the appropriate name (eg, "BAL 080114") in the appropriate folder and opens it, at which point the operator then closes the template, and continues work in the new copy.

The folder structure is:

```
Drive
--->Ops Room
------->Procedural Sheets
----------->Night Shift
--------------->Balancing
------------------->2014
----------------------->01-2014
...
----------------------->12-2014
```

We are trying to transition this to Google docs spreadsheets, and mostly it's working.  But I cannot find a method to allow someone to open the template (stored in Balancing), run a "Start New Day" script, and have the script create the file in the proper sub-sub-folder.  To wit, for 08/01/2014, the file should be stored in Balancing/2014/08-2014 as Bal 080114.

This is what I have thus far:

```
function startNewDay() {
  // This code makes a copy of the current spreadsheet and names it appropriately
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // The file name is created and stored on sheet "Set Date" in cell B5
  var fname = ss.getSheetByName("Set Date").getRange("B5").getValue();
  var folderYear = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "yyyy"); // top-level folder is by year in yyyy format
  var folderMonth = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "MM-yyyy"); // folder name is in mm-yyyy format
  //the above is probably overkill, but I'll work on efficiency once I get it working at all :
  //Everything works up to this point...

  //This is where I start running into problems...
  //The Master Copy SSID is <redacted>
  var SSID = '<redacted>'
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folderYear + "/" + folderMonth); 
  var backup = DocsList.getFileById(SSID).makeCopy(fname);
  backup.addToFolder(folder); //This line will move the file to the appropriate folder
  backup.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder()); //This line is needed to remove the File from the Root
}
```

I borrowed the backup.* stuff from another StackOverFlow answer that had similar properties, but my version doesn't create the file.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible in Drive?  Or will I just need to have the operators create a copy and then move it manually?

I apologize for any scripting ignorance - I've just started learning Google script this week, and I'm having trouble finding a common ground with my previous VB experience.

Thanks in advance for any help.

James

Comment: What is your error message / problem / challenge?

Comment: If your question is: can I copy a file in GDrive and save it to some location on GDrive (correct me if I am wrong) then the answer is yes.

Comment: The problem is the ssid you are using...this is not a valid ssid,get it using ss.getId() and you will see what I mean. Use Logger.log(ss.getId()) and look at the Logger. Subsidiary question: does the destination folder already exist ?

Comment: Matcheek - problem is that the file is not being created in the directory in which I need it to be.

Comment: Serge - <redacted> means that the SSID I had in there was removed due to privacy issues - I can't allow the spreadsheet to be exposed to the public.  I do have a working SSID.  Subsidiary question's answer:  Yes.

Comment: Matcheek - yes, the operator can copy the file by hand.  What I would prefer to do is allow an operator to click and run a script, which would copy the template file to a new file, appropriately named and placed, then switch the operator to that (new) spreadsheet.

Comment: I don't see where a new folder is created?  Or is that done manually?

Comment: Sandy - folders are created manually.  All I need to do is to allow the operator to open a template spreadsheet, then (via script) create a copy of the spreadsheet with a set name, move that copy to the specified (already created) folder, and open the copy for editing.  Clear as mud? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to comment so I cannot add on to what is already there.

Are the folders that are "manually" being created being created with the correct permissions by the correct person?  Shared Folders can get tricky on Google Drive.

I may even suggest something like this and have the script just create the folders for you:

```
/*********************************************************
 * Function to determine the destination folder based on
 *   provided criteria.
 *
 * @param {Folder} root The root folder.
 * @param {String} folderYear The year of the report.
 * @param {String} folderMonth The month of the report.
 * @return {Folder} Destination Folder.
 *********************************************************/
function returnFolder(root, folderYear, folderMonth) {
  var dir      = DocsList.getFolderById(root);
  var folders  = DocsList.getFolderById(root).getFolders();
  var found    = false;
  var toReturn = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    if (folders[i].getName() == folderYear) {
      dir      = folders[i];
      found    = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    dir = dir.createFolder(folderYear);
    folders = dir.getFolders();
  }
  else found = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++)
    if (folders[i].getName() == folderMonth) {
      toReturn = folders[i].getId();
      found    = true;
      break;
    }

  if (!found) toReturn = dir.createFolder(folderMonth).getId();
  return DocsList.getFolderById(toReturn);
}
```

Then your code would be as follows:

```
var SSID = '<redacted>'
var folder = returnFolder(OBJECT_PARENT_FOLDER, folderYear, folderMonth);
var backup = DocsList.getFileById(SSID).makeCopy(fname);
backup.addToFolder(folder); //This line will move the file to the appropriate folder
backup.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder()); //This line is needed to remove the File from the Root
```

You will need to match the code to your needs, but I hope this helps.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the code!  Unfortunately, I'm running into a weird error with it. Even if I use "var OBJECT_PARENT_FOLDER = DocsList.getFolderById(idName);" (where idName is the SSID of my /Procedural Sheets), the returnFolder function you have created tells me "No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it" at the "var dir =" statement.  I created the /Procedural Sheets folder, so I *should* have root privs to it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Forgot to put this in:  I did two Logger.Log commands:  Logger.log(OBJECT_PARENT_FOLDER); and 
Logger.log(OBJECT_PARENT_FOLDER.getName()); on the OBJECT_... variable, and it reports that it *is* in fact the correct folder name.

Comment: @J.Moore Hello,

Sorry.  I guess I was not clear enough.  The OBJECT_PARENT_FOLDER was where you need to replace that text with a Folder object.  From the given information, Looks like you would want to pass the "Balancing" Folder object.  Does that make sense?

Comment: CV - I changed it to the following:  var folder = returnFolder(DocsList.getFolderById('0B1InJScpiGdino5wckpsa3UxUDg'), folderYear, folderMonth);  Still getting the same error.  (The SSID is purposely corrupted for security reasons.)  Is this what I was supposed to use?

Comment: Just trying to help you troubleshoot.  Are you sure you've got the right "Id"?  Could you do some debugging using DocsList functions and Logger.log() functions? I have a feeling there's a mistake in the file ID or permissions.

Comment: logger.log(root), inside function returnFolder, tells me that root is a folder, but I can't get it to tell me what value is being passed.  I'm logging the root value before any other steps in the function.  As to the right ID, outside returnFolder the following: var OBJECT_PARENT_FOLDER = DocsList.getFolderById('0B1InJScpiGdino5wckpsa3UxUDg'));
  Logger.log(OBJECT_PARENT_FOLDER);
  Logger.log(OBJECT_PARENT_FOLDER.getName());
returns the correct pathname.  Using the variable OBJECT_PARENT_FOLDER vs using the hardcoded docslist object, at least to me, shouldn't matter.  Should it?

Comment: OK.  I'm an idiot. :) I was trying to pass the wrong information into CV's function.  I passed the correct information (the ID of the "root" directory for the Balancing files), and it worked (mostly).  The code that CVNNTG posted above is great, but if you use it, be aware that there is a slight typo:  "if (!found) toReturn = did.createFolder" should be "if (!found) toReturn = dir.createFolder".  Aside from that, I'm still running into a small error at the end of the function, "TypeError: Cannot find function getId in object ".  I'm trying to figure that one out on my own.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.  ]=  Can you tell me which line and function is causing the code error?

Comment: No problem. :) I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot find function getId in object " on the last line of returnFolder: "return DocsList.getFolderById(toReturn.getId());".  From what I can see, toReturn is attempting to return an ID that is "0B1InJScpIgyamZ1lMTk2ZjhjNS1jNTY8TLQ2NDgtYWJhNy05Mzk3NDZhYmE2Mjk".

Comment: @J.Moore I changed the last two lines of my function.  I had errors in there.  Sorry.  Try it now, please.

Comment: That fixed it! Now if I can just figure out how to keep it from creating a new 08-2014 each time it runs.  I'll see if I can't do that part on my own.  Best way to learn.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @J.Moore Hm... the code I wrote should only create a folder if it can't be found...

Comment: I just took out the next to last line: "if (!found) toReturn = dir.createFolder(folderMonth).getId();" and it works like it's supposed to.  I dunno.  Granted, I probably broke the functionality of creating a folder if it's missing, but that's not an issue, as that task is supposed to be performed by the operators as part of monthly / yearly house-keeping.