# Generate new spreadsheet from a selected row based on template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With this script I can generate new tab from all the row in a spreadsheet:

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Tab Orari')
        .addItem('Genera Tab Orari', 'createTabs')
        .addToUi()}

function createTabs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('xxx');
  ss.getSheetByName('Generale').getRange('I2:I').getValues().filter(String)
  .forEach(function (sn) {
    if (!ss.getSheetByName(sn[0])) {
      ss.insertSheet(sn[0], ss.getSheets().length, {template: templateSheet});
    }
  });
}
```

I would generate a new spreadsheet (and so not a tab), based on a template tab (in this case, the tab "xxx") only when I select a specific row and rename this Spreadsheet as the value in the cell in column I for that corresponding row.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Instead of `insertSheet` use [`copyTo(spreadsheet)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)

The spreadsheet name can be obtained by obtaining the row number of the selected cell and finding the entry in column 9 ("I") of this row.

**Sample:**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Tab Orari')
  .addItem('Genera spreadsheet', 'createSpreadsheet')
  .addToUi()}

function createSpreadsheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // the following line means that the function will search for the spreadsheet name in the active sheet, no matter which one it is
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //the selected row
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  // column 9 corresponds to "I"
  var name = sheet.getRange(row, 9).getValue();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('xxx');
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
  templateSheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. Two question: 1) How can I set the destination folder? 2) The spreadsheet created has 2 tabs ('Copy of xxx' and 'Sheet 1'). Can I have only 1 tab with the same name of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Glad to help! To your questions:2. `Sheet1` is created by default, you can remove it after creation with the line `newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));` at the end of the script ` 1. Unfortunately `SpreadsheetApp.create()` does not allow to specify the folder, you would need to move the spreadsheet manually after creation, e.g. with `addToFolder` and `removeFormFolder` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084463/i-need-to-save-a-copy-of-a-google-spreadsheet-to-a-specific-directory-using-scri) sample.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. And if I would to insert in the new spreadsheet 2 tabs?

Comment: Then you perform the same request for both tabs.E.g. `templateSheet1.copyTo(newSpreadsheet); templateSheet2.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);`

Comment: Done myself! Thanks anyway.

Comment: One last thing... How can I give (in the new spreadsheet) to the tab1, the same name of the new spreadsheet, to the tab2, a custom name?

Comment: Not entirely sure if I understood you correctly, but in general, to rename sheets in `newSpreadsheet`, use `newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("oldName").setName("newName");`

Comment: I have this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setName' of null   https://imgur.com/TsIGecF

Comment: This error means that the sheet with the specified name does not exist. This is because when the sheet get copied, the name changes to `Copy of XXX`. An elegant way to solve the issue is to rename the sheet directly when copying: `templateSheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("newName");`

Comment: Good. Now the last problem is only the folder where the new spreadsheet will be generated.

Comment: This is a bit deviated from the original question. I recommend you totr y and implement it like in [this] sample and if you encoutner problems - post a new question with your complete updated code and a detailed description of the difficulties you encountered.