# Copy Value from a Spreadsheet to another based on a Template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With this script ( [Generate new spreadsheet from a selected row based on template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62424905/generate-new-spreadsheet-from-a-selected-row-based-on-template) ) I can generate a new spreadsheet (and so not a tab), based on a template tab (in this case, the tab "xxx") only when I select a specific row and rename this Spreadsheet as the value in the cell in column B for that corresponding row.
Now, I would copy the value of the cell A2 from the source spreadsheet into the tab "xxx" in the cell A3.

How to do that?

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Genera Scheda')
  .addItem('Genera Scheda', 'createSpreadsheet')
  .addToUi()}

function createSpreadsheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // the following line means that the function will search for the spreadsheet name in the active sheet, no matter which one it is
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //the selected row
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  // column 2 corresponds to "B"
  var name = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var templateSheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('xxx');
  var templateSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('xxx2');
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
  var fileId = newSpreadsheet.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var folderId ="-----";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  templateSheet1.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Scheda");
  templateSheet2.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Import")
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Foglio1"));
  folder.addFile(file);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To copy individual cell values between tabs and spreadsheets, a good solution is to use [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) and [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

This methods must be applied to range objects (that is the cells).

Sample:

```js
...
// define sheet either as the active sheet or specify it with sheet = ss.getSheetByName("XXX");
var myValue = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("xxx").getRange("A3").setValue(myValue);
...
```

Note that if you want to get / set values of more than one cell simulataneously, you need to use `getValues()` and `setValues()` instead.

UPDATE

Full code based on your situation:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Genera Scheda')
  .addItem('Genera Scheda', 'createSpreadsheet')
  .addToUi()}

function createSpreadsheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // the following line means that the function will search for the spreadsheet name in the active sheet, no matter which one it is
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //the selected row
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  // column 2 corresponds to "B"
  var name = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var templateSheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('xxx');
  var templateSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('xxx2');
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
  var fileId = newSpreadsheet.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var folderId ="-----";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  templateSheet1.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Scheda");
  templateSheet2.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Import")
  var myValue = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Scheda").getRange("A3").setValue(myValue);
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Foglio1"));
  folder.addFile(file);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is my code: https://imgur.com/7ceckPh but I have this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null

Comment: Sounds like you do not have in your new spreadsheet a sheet called "xxx". Do you want to set the value into `A3` of the old or new spreadsheet?

Comment: In this case you need to add the two lines of my answer AFTER copying the sheet "xxx" from the old to the new spreadsheet - before this this sheet does not exist.

Comment: I just did, mind that in your line `templateSheet1.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Scheda");` you renamed `xxx` to `Scheda`, so you need to adapt `newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("xxx").getRange("A3").setValue(myValue);` accordingly changing `xxx` to `Scheda`. I hope it is clearer now!

Comment: The code works. Now how can I copy from the old sheet the corrisponding cell of the row selected in col A to the new ?

Comment: I am glad it works for yoou! You mean you want to run the code while a cell is selected and retrieve the to be copied range dynamically on selection?

Comment: Yes! When I select the row to generate the new sheet.

Comment: You can get the active row with `var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow()`.  And then `var myValue = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();` to get the value in column 1 (A) and active row. I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Can you update the script with this new feature, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216568/discussion-between-popoff-and-ziganotschka).

Comment: Thanks. Sure. I'll do it